# Training Individual-Level Predictor using Distribution of Group-level Data

Tags: machine-learning, bootstrap, multiple-imputation, train, aggregation

I have a problem in which I'm looking to train an individual-level predictor for outcomes. I have information on individual-level covariates, but I don't have individual-level outcome variables. Instead, for each individual, I have detailed information about the distribution of outcomes in the group they fall into.
I know that trying to predict the individual mean using a predictor trained on group-level means is tricky due to the ecological fallacy. Given that I have detailed information on the group-level distributions, is it possible to do train an individual-level predictor in a principled way? For instance, can I impute individual-level outcomes in training data by taking a draw from the entire distribution of group-level outcomes?
Further, is it possible to do this more than once per individual? Is it valid to insert the same set of covariates into the training data with different outcomes, each one drawn independently from the known distribution of possible outcomes?

I have a large amount of individual-level demographic data, and I'm trying to use it to predict income. I have detailed data on the distribution of income in the area in which the individuals live, but don't have any information about individual-level income for any of the people.

Comment: I think this Q wil benefit from more context and details, like total sample size, number of groups, and why this strange setup?

Comment: I have a large amount of individual-level demographic data, and I'm trying to use it to predict income. I have detailed data on the distribution of income in the area in which the individuals live, but don't have any information about individual-level income for any of the people.

Comment: Please write that new info as an edit to the post, it is important. This kind of nonstandard problems is where contextual information can be very helpful. Also, tell us what is the purpose of the modeling exercise. You cannot create information you do not have, but there must be some external knowledge about demographic variables and income, which could be used to construct an (multiple) imputation model!

Comment: Thanks for the help, I've updated the post with further information. I have to imagine that there is some external information that would let me see the relationship between some subset of the characteristics that I want and income on an individual level, but I have access to a variety of non-standard characteristics that I doubt would be included in any administrative data set (say, the model of car that a person drives). Is there any way that you know of to use mutliple imputation with multiple draws from the distribution, without having any concrete information on the relationship between

Comment: user characteristics and income on the individual level? So, is there any way to identify this using simply the covariance between individual characteristics and the distribution of income at the aggregated level?